# Python: Function to find out if a tuple contains even numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So what I want is a function that gets a tuple input from a user and then figures out if that tuple contains an even number. I want to know how to do it with a for or while loop. I've tried it but the code doesn't work. I've kind of got something but it's not working:

```
def ifEven(x):
    i = -1
    if isinstance(x, tuple):
        while i < len(x):
            for i in x:
                i = i + 1
                if x[i] % 2 == 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to use a `for` or a `while` loop? Python's efficiency comes from its generators and list comprehension

Comment: It's generally not good to restrict your code to only one type of argument like you have, is it really important that the argument is a tuple? Ducktyping and generality is one of the characteristics of Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the documentation about `for` statement in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements.

Here is a working code:

```
def ifEven(x):
    if isinstance(x, tuple):
        for i in x:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                return True
    return False
```

That being said, it can be rewritten as a one-liner using Python's generator expressions:

```
def isEven(x):
    return any(v % 2 == 0 for v in x)
```

Comment: Don't bother with that.  Just use `any()`.

Comment: @Kevin, The OP asked for a `for` loop, not `any`.

Comment: @merlin2011: A generator expression is still a `for` loop in my book.

Comment: You can use just `return any(v % 2 == 0 for v in x)`. No need to create a list. Or `return any(v % 2 == 0 for v in x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else False` to include the check for tuple

Answer (score 0):

You indentation looks a bit off but that might just be how you copy/pasted.  True is "True" in python not "true" as in your return function which might also be messing you up.

Answer (score 0):

In `for` loop `i` itself initializes and start iterating over the tuple. The content of `i` at each iteration is one of the element from the tuple.
Let's have a deeper look into it. let your tuple be `(3, 4, 6, 7)`
In first iteration :-

```
for i in x     # i=3
    i = i+1    # i = 4
    if x[i] %2 == 0 :    # x[4] % 2 == 0  => This will give you IndexError, since there is no index 4 in the tuple x(python uses zero based indexing)
```

So you don't need to increment `i` separately as `for` increments the iterating variable upto the end of the sequence provided (in your case it's upto the last element in the tuple `x`)

And since `i` posses the element from the tuple itself, so by incrementing it you are incrementing the value in `i`. And then you are accessing the element with incremented index from the tuple. That is, if tuple element is `3`, you are first incrementing it by 1, so it becomes `4`, and then you are checking whether the element in 4th index of the tuple is even or not i.e. if `x[4]` is even or not. But since the tuple that I have considered, is of lengthe 4, so it will throw `IndexError`

So, here you don't need to initialize `i = -1`, don't need to use `while`, no need to increment `i` inside `for` loop. Rest solution is given by Selcuk.