# Input with tuple and choosing odd or even

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function that returns true if any of the inputted numbers are even.  1.) I do not know how to make python return true if both odd and even numbers are inputted.  For example, one input could be (1,2,3,4).  To me, that is true, but not to my function.  I only know how to tell python what is odd and what is even.  2.)  The input has to be in tuple form, and I only know how to input in (x,y) form.

This is what I have so far:

```python
def any_even(tuple):
    """returns true if tuple has any even integers in it
    int -> int"""
    if tuple % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Function to find out if a tuple contains even numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444532/python-function-to-find-out-if-a-tuple-contains-even-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def any_even(foo):
    for i in foo:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return True
    return False
```

You got the correct idea, however, you must iterate over the tuple
just like you would in a list.

Comment: Not sure why that didnt work: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
    any_even(2,3)
TypeError: any_even() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: your input must be `any_even( (x,y,z) )` you had it `any_even(x,y)`

Comment: can you post the working function? still having trouble

Comment: `any_even((2,3))` instead of `any_even(2,3) `

Comment: oh, the input has to be in that form. i got it, thanks

Comment: `tuple` is a built-in. I'd change that.

Answer (score 0):

```
any_even = lambda x: sum([1 for i in x if i % 2 == 0]) > 0
```